# Troubles with the SQLDataSource object

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

Now I know why I just use MySQL and unbound objects... this SQLDataSource thing is for the birds... anyways, since I *have* to use it for my project, I've got a .ascx user control with a repeater attached to an SQLDataSource object. I'm trying to dynamically pass in a parameter based on a selection in a dropdown box on the parent page. However, I can't extract the value from the dropdown box because the user control binds first! How can I make the user control bind AFTER i get the value from the dropdown?

thanks

**EDIT:** here's some code. i'm new at this whole databound object thing, so please be gentle :)

**Parent Page HTML**

```
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="ddUsers" autopostback="true"
 datasourceid="sqlUsers" datatextfield="username" datavaluefield="userid" />
<asp:sqldatasource runat="server" id="sqlUsers" 
 selectcommand="SELECT * FROM [users]" connectionstring="<%$ 
 ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" />

....
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <pa:photolist runat="server" id="plGallery" albumid="0" />
    </ul>
</div>
....
```

**Parent Page Codebehind**

```
Private Sub ddUsers_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object,
 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddUsers.DataBound
    Dim id As Integer = ddUsers.SelectedValue
End Sub
```

**UC HTML**

```
<asp:repeater runat="server" id="rPhotos" datasourceid="sqlPhotos">
    <itemtemplate>
      Stuff
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
<asp:sqldatasource runat="server" id="sqlPhotos"
 selectcommand='SELECT * FROM PhotosWithTags 
  WHERE userid=@userid AND albumid=@albumid'
 connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" >
    <selectparameters>
         <asp:parameter name="albumid" defaultvalue="0" />
         <asp:parameter name="userid" defaultvalue="1" />
    </selectparameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

**UC Codebehind**

```
Partial Public Class photolist : Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
Private _albumid As Integer
Public Property AlbumID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _albumid
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _albumid = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _userid As Integer
Public Property UserID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _userid
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _userid = value
    End Set
End Property
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, 
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    sqlPhotos.SelectParameters("userid").DefaultValue = UserID
    sqlPhotos.SelectParameters("albumid").DefaultValue = AlbumID
End Sub
End Class
```

Still having problems with this :\ anyone have any ideas? thanks...

Comment: PS, the database is fine, and the user control is registered fine. the issue is the UC's data source not getting the variable in time because it binds first, for some reason.

Comment: You should provide this details when you have ask question, I answer according to your details and get down vote :)

Comment: you probably got downvoted because your answer isn't helpful.

Comment: If answer is not helpful that's does't mean give down vote

Comment: and also you give not details like now...

Comment: if you could help me, i'm sure i could upvote you to counteract the downvote.

Comment: No need of vote, thanks anyway